# why isn't my error message working?

Tags: php

I've got a simple form for a `$_Session` and it's not printing my error message when the password is wrong. It works fine other than the error message and in fact the error message worked until I put `header("Location: /cms/");` in. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

```
<?php 
session_start();
$error_msg = "";

if($_POST['username']) {

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$admin = "a";
$adminpass = "s";

if(($username != $admin) || ($password != $adminpass)) {
$error_msg = 'Your login information is wrong dude!';
} 
else {
    $_SESSION['admin'] = '$username';
        header("Location: /cms/");
    exit();
}

}
if(!isset($_SESSION['admin'])) {
    header("Location: /cms/login");     
exit();
}
?>

<html>
<body>

<form action="/cms/loggedin.php" method="post" target=_self> 
<label>Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username"></label>
<font color="#FF0000"><?php echo $error_msg; ?></font><br />

<br />
<label>Password: <input type="text" name="password" id="password"></label>
<br />
<br />
<label><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Sign In"></label>
</form>
```

Comment: Hmm, not sure about your problem, but  $_SESSION['admin'] = '$username'; looks also wrong. You would probably want to remove the quotes there

Comment: I'm surprised the if(!isset($_SESSION['admin'])) block doesn't create an infinite loop.  Either your password info is accepted, or your redirected to another page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`header("Location: /cms/");` - this will redirect to a different page before the message is printed, so you will not see the message.

EDIT - In fact it is the `header("Location: /cms/login");` that will do the redirect as in case of the error, it will not find the session variable.

Comment: It depends on which page this is. Is it the login page itself, which it seems like? In that case you do not need to redirect.

Comment: So should I put `if(!isset($_SESSION['admin'])) {
    header("Location: /cms/login");     
exit();
}
` in another file and include it on the pages I don't want people that haven't logged in to access? Or is there a better way? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can use that as a basic authentication check, considering that you are using a simple way for authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you should change..

At the point where you check for username and password :

```
if(($username != $admin) || ($password != $adminpass)) {
  $_SESSION['error'] = 'Your login information is wrong dude!';
}
```

In the HTML part:

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_SESSION['error']))
    {
        echo '<p class="warning">',$_SESSION['error'],'</p>'; 
        unset( $_SESSION['error'] );
    }
?>
```

Also, please learn how to write proper semantic HTML. The `<font>` tag has been deprecated for ~10 years already, your code is missing `<!DOCTYPE` of any kind and `<br>` tag is not for formating the layout.

Oh, and you might find [this article](http://codeangel.org/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html) interesting.

Comment: Thanks! And it's okay, you can relax...I don't use `<font>` tags, I just didn't include `<!DOCTYPE>` in my question nor use `<br> tags for formatting...it was just a test page I was running on my end. :)

Comment: @Josh , did you look at what is store in session ? `var_dump( $_SESSION );`